# how to limit row number to one unique row in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to limit the row number to one unique row in SQL query. Here's sample data to recognize what I'm talking about:

```
john doe 3000 fog horn drive , ky 40444
john doe 3001 merry lane , ky 40484
```

I want to return the first one in the list here's my query :

```
Select 
    DISTINCT p.personID, e.citizenship, 
    rtrim(i.lastname + CASE WHEN i.suffix IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' + i.suffix END) + ', ' + i.firstname + (CASE WHEN i.middlename IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' + i.middlename END) StuName, 
    e.grade, i.gender, p.studentNumber, e.citizenship, e.adult, i.birthdate, 
    e.disability1, e.disability2, ad.city, e.displacedHomemaker, e.homeSchooled, 
    e.localStudentNumber, e.migrant, e.modifiedDate, e.modifiedByID,
    rtrim(Staff.lastname + CASE WHEN Staff.suffix IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' + Staff.suffix END) + ', ' + Staff.firstname + (CASE WHEN Staff.middlename IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' + Staff.middleName END) Staffname, 
    Staff.personID Staffid, i.lastname, i.firstname, i.middlename, i.ssn, 
    ad.phone, ad.state, ad.zip, ad.addressLine1
FROM 
    Person p 
LEFT join 
    Enrollment e ON e.personID = p.personID And isnull(e.noshow, 0) = 0 
LEFT join 
    EnrollmentKY ky ON ky.enrollmentID = e.enrollmentID 
LEFT join 
    [Identity] i ON i.identityID = p.currentIdentityID And i.personID = p.personID 
INNER join 
    Calendar c ON c.calendarID = e.calendarID 
INNER join 
    SchoolYear sy ON sy.endYear = c.endYear AND sy.active = 1 
JOIN 
    staffMember Staff ON Staff.personID = e.modifiedByID 
--join view_students s ON  s.personID = i.personID
left join 
    v_MailingAddress ad ON ad.personID = i.personID And ad.relatedBy = 'household'
                        And ad.endDate IS NULL And isnull(ad.secondary, 0) = 0 
order by 
    i.lastname, i.firstname, i.middlename
```

edit: need to only pick first row in SQL code because I have a problem with people that have multiple addresses it puts two rows for them and i only need first row of data for the person that has multiple addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `personId` is distinct for each of the records and they just have a different address, then you can add a field for the `row_number()` and then only select the records where the `row_number = 1`:

```
select *
from 
(
  Select p.personID,
    e.citizenship, 
    rtrim(i.lastname + CASE WHEN i.suffix IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' + i.suffix END) + ', ' + i.firstname + (CASE WHEN i.middlename IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' + i.middlename END) StuName, 
    e.grade, 
    i.gender, 
    p.studentNumber, 
    e.citizenship, 
    e.adult, 
    i.birthdate, 
    e.disability1, 
    e.disability2, 
    ad.city, 
    e.displacedHomemaker, 
    e.homeSchooled,
    e.localStudentNumber,
    e.migrant,
    e.modifiedDate,
    e.modifiedByID,
    rtrim(Staff.lastname + CASE WHEN Staff.suffix IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' + Staff.suffix END) + ', ' + Staff.firstname + (CASE WHEN Staff.middlename IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' + Staff.middleName END) Staffname, 
    Staff.personID Staffid,
    i.lastname, 
    i.firstname, 
    i.middlename,
    i.ssn, 
    ad.phone, 
    ad.state, 
    ad.zip, 
    ad.addressLine1,
    row_number() over(partition by p.personid order by p.personid) rn -- add this field
  FROM Person p 
  LEFT join Enrollment e 
    ON e.personID = p.personID 
    And isnull(e.noshow,0)=0 
  LEFT join EnrollmentKY ky 
    ON ky.enrollmentID = e.enrollmentID 
  LEFT join [Identity] i 
    ON i.identityID = p.currentIdentityID 
    And i.personID = p.personID 
  INNER join Calendar c 
    ON c.calendarID = e.calendarID 
  INNER join SchoolYear sy 
    ON sy.endYear = c.endYear 
    AND sy.active = 1 
  JOIN staffMember Staff 
    ON Staff.personID = e.modifiedByID 
  --join view_students s ON  s.personID = i.personID
  left join v_MailingAddress ad 
    ON ad.personID = i.personID 
    And ad.relatedBy = 'household'
    And ad.endDate IS NULL 
    And isnull(ad.secondary,0)=0 
) x
where x.rn = 1
order by x.lastname, x.firstname, x.middlename
```

Comment: double checking this helpful hint but it seesm to work so far.

Comment: it works and only pulls one address but i think whoever did data entry for one person put two primary addresses. So i think it was the person that did data entry that is to blame for this. Thanks

Comment: oh change the order by to x.lastname and so on and it will  work for anyone viewing this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `LIMIT` to limit the no. of outputs.

Eg:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY CONDITION
LIMIT NO_OF_ROWS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a "GROUP BY" clause instead of the DISTINCT keyword?

Also, what about a Sub-Query?  If I were writing this type of thing I'd use a sproc and create a temporary table.

Comment: only have read only and execute permissions so thats not possible. will try group by clause though.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:  Deleted original answer as question was changed and original answer is not the way to go with changed question.

Suggest GROUP BY clause per Neil Hoskins.

Comment: @lamak The OP asked to return one row. Select Top 1 returns one row. I have the same question as Bluefeet about how the OP will decide which row to return, but we don't have that information. I thougth maybe we could get it with some discussion. I don't think I merit a downvote.  If you have an answer, why don't you put it out there?

Comment: please look at edit above i updated information to mean one row of unique data for each person pulled. Also, i have tryed this its irrelevant to my needs.

Comment: @jeffery  Well, that is a different question entirely.  If that is what you want then Neil Hoskins probably has it with his GROUP BY suggestion.

Comment: @mikeY - A downvote is a way to express when I feel that the answer is not useful (as the tooltip says), I don't need to provide an answer. Actually, I didn't even need to leave a comment, but I did, but I guess that was a mistake since now I have two downvotes on other answers by an "anonymous" user.